# How to use Range.Formula using variable range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to calculate the average of a range and I need to update it for every step of a loop; practically, I need to move the range 1 row up every step. For example, let's suppose that I want to calculate the average of the data between D19:D35, and for every step of a for loop I want to move the range by 1 row up.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```vb
For x = 3 To 1 Step -1
    Dim z, w As Integer
    z = x + 16
    w = x + 31

    Range("D13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(D" & z & ":D & w &)"
Next
```

Comment: It won't work because `w` is inside the quotes. You don't need a loop for this though. And you're just overwriting `D13`.

Comment: I have a bigger code with other formula inside the loop. I've just posted this to simplify.

Comment: You can write a formula to a range in one go. You don't need a loop. But in any case, `w` shouldn't be inside the quotes.

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling. Anyway, I need to calculate the average in each step because if other conditions are not met, the loop will stop and I need to have the last average

Comment: Fair enough. Then all you need to do is fix the `w`.

Comment: Thank you BigBen :)

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Even the syntax highlighting here on this website is telling you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your variable 'w' outside of the double quotes like so:

```
Range("D13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(D" & z & ":D" & w & ")"
```